# Declaring Export Compliance to false in Info.plist doesn't bypass the submission process on the App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have a native macOS Cocoa app in Swift.

I have read the [Complying with Encryption Export Regulations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations) article from Apple. I did add the `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` property key to my app's `Info.plist` and set the value to `NO`.

Every time I upload my build to the App Store Connect, I have to fill in the export compliance. Which is very annoying because Apple's article state that you can bypass and streamline the submission process. Yet, it is not working for me.